# Is there a way to log only REST request bodies that fail with an internal server error in Spring

Tags: rest, spring-aop

I am trying to log the request bodies for REST services(POST request body) that fail when there is some kind of internal server error. I don't want to log all the request bodies as that will take a lot of memory on my disc.

The exception is happening somewhere in the dao layer (like a Key constraint or some kind of unhandled exception), where I don't have the access to the entire request.

I tried using some aop advices(after-throws) but I was not able to log the required information.

Can someone suggest an approach that needs to be followed to log the request body.

I use RESTful(javax.ws.rs) webservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no response was given, I ended up using a filter http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/web/filter/AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.html